# Installing GDAL python binding Linux

Tags: python, linux, gdal

I've been trying to install the python GDAL binding from source with ./configure --with-python but when i attemp

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
   _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems to me to be an error with swig.

Comment: Are you able to run any of the gdal utilities from the command line (e.g., gdalinfo)?

Comment: yes, i can. Is it possible to use that somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GDAL installed and `libgdal.so` exists, it looks like the python module is just not finding the library. You can try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the directory containing `libgdal.so` (e.g. `/usr/local/lib`). If that works, run **ldconfig** to update your library settings so you won't have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` every time (which many consider a [bad idea](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/avoiding_ld_library_path_the)).

Answer (score 2):

You Can try

```
sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2 libgdal1h
```

and then try importing